# How to create a numpy vector from this text file containing both strings and numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

CONSIDER  my data set contains the following records

```
1991    5   4   3   42  54.5            *   PANAMA: CHANGUINOLA, ALMIRANTE, BOCAS DEL TORO  9.542   -82.418 10  6.2             36  1       2                   
1991    5   15  14  28  50.1            *   GEORGIA: KHEKHETI   42.565  43.349  14  4.9 5       1               1   45  1           
1991    5   26  10  59  48.9            *   MALAYSIA: KALIMANTAN: RANAU 5.865   116.746 33  4.5     1   1               1                   

1991    6   15  0   59  20.3            *   GEORGIA: DZHAVA, TSKHINVALI, OSSETIA    42.461  44.009  9   6.1 8   8   1   200 3       3                   

1991    6   15  11  15  28.0        Vol *   PHILIPPINES: LUZON: MANILA, PINATUBO ERUPTION   15.119  120.355 10  5.5
```

How can I create a feature vector, that can be used as an input to the neural network that uses gradient descent and backpropagation...

I want to convert the text to vector and also ultimately create a numpy vector in python...

Comment: What should the vector look like?

Comment: Vector should contain only numbers and each record may be mapped to each row of the resulting 2-d dimensional vector

Comment: What do you want to do with text entries exactly? Can you provide the desired output, e.g. for the first line?

Comment: Actually I don't know how the output should look like... I want to give the output vector as an input data set to this program https://github.com/lzhengchun/a-simple-neural-network-on-spark/blob/master/ann_spark.ipynb